# Highlight odd lines with QSyntaxHighlighter

Tags: qt, qtgui

As far as I know, I have to inherit from `QSyntaxHighlighter` and and override `highlightBlock()` to make a highlighter for my `QTextEdit`.

However, I can only get a `QString` in `highlightBlock()`. The string does not contain any information about where it is in that document. How can I do if I want to highlight the text only in odd lines of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSyntaxHighlighter has this

```
protected:
QTextBlock currentBlock() const;
```

where you can find `blockNumber()`